# Dynamically positioning a GWT widget

Tags: gwt

My Goal is to have a Button with a background image and ontop of these a Label.
I want to position the label in the centre of the button and vertically allign it's text. I want the button to expand in propotion to the number of characters in the label. What is the best type of panel to use to build this type of composite widget as I am running into problems with using an AbsolutePanel as it doesn't dynamically grow with it's child elements.

```
private PushButton button;
private Label label = new Label();
private AbsolutePanel panel = new AbsolutePanel();
private Image image = new Image("images/rectangle_blue.png");

public ExpandingRectangularButton(String text)
{
    label.setText(text);
    String width = "120px";
    String height = "160px";
    image.setWidth(width);
    image.setHeight(height);
    button = new PushButton(image);

    panel.add(button, 0, 0);
    panel.setWidth(width);
    panel.setHeight(height);
    initWidget( panel );
}
```

What is the best type of panel to use in this case?  I have tried flow, horizontal and flextables but I can't get these to stack widgets on top of each other correctly

Comment: have you tried with CSS's to do this.. you can keep image as bg of label, text-align: center

Answer (score 0):

[FlowPanel??](http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/latest/com/google/gwt/user/client/ui/FlowPanel.html).

A [FlowPanel](https://developers.google.com/web-toolkit/tools/gwtdesigner/layoutmanagers/gwt/flowpanel) arranges components in a directional flow, much like lines of text in a paragraph.

Comment: How can I place a label ontop of an image using a flowpanel?

Comment: My choice is with safehtml..instead of many lines of java code.

Comment: I would agree with SCK, you can set the image as the background of the FlowPanel and put the Label in the FlowPanel.

Comment: @NickD Fine. :).I just suggested flowpanel.After flowpanel we can do it in many ways.